# I am unable give the output BUST

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given three integers between 1 and 11 if their sum is less than or equal to 21 , return their sum.

If sum exceeds 21 and there is a 11, reduce the total sum by 10.

Finally, if sum(even after the adjustment) exceeds 21, return `BUST`.

```
def func(a,b,c ):
    while((a,b,c)in range (1,12)):
        sum=a+b+c
        if sum<=21:
            return sum
        if sum>21 and 11 in (a,b,c):
            sum=sum-10
            if sum>21:
                return "Bust"
print(func(9,9,9))
```

Comment: What should be done if the sum exceeds 21 and there is no 11 ? Your function returns nothing for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need:

```
def adj_sum(a,b,c):
    s = a+b+c
    if s <= 21:
        return s
    elif s>21 and 11 in (a,b,c):
        s = s -10
        
    result = s if s<=21 else "bust"
    return result

print(adj_sum(9,9,9))
# Bust

print(adj_sum(9,9,11))
# 19
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
def func(a, b, c):
  abc = (a, b, c)
  sum_abc = sum(abc)
  if sum_abc > 21 and 11 in abc:
    sum_abc -= 10
  return "BUST" if sum_abc > 21 else sum_abc

print(func(9,9,9))
```

Comment: print(func(9,9,9))
"Bust"
print(func(9,9,11))
19
These are the test cases

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def func(a,b,c):
    def check(x):
        return x in range(1,12)
    if check(a) and check(b) and check(c):
        vars = [a,b,c]
        res = sum(vars)
        if res <= 21:
            return res
        elif res > 21:
            if 11 in vars:
                res -= 10
            
        return res if res < 21 else 'Bust'
```

Comment: @Mounika - This is what you needed. Passes all check and conditions. Try this